# Scrape and list all addresses of transfers on a specific contract address

Tags: solidity, etherscan

I'd like to scrape all addresses that transferred tokens from a token address (bought) in a specific block.

Reason is wanting to manually blacklist anyone that bought a token in a certain block.

Comment: Could you add more details about your use case - do you want to dynamically access this data from inside a contract? If not, you might be better off using a [Dune](https://dune.xyz/) query instead

Comment: No, I didn't mean from inside a contract. Just by any means necessary, so that I can manually blacklist the scraped addresses through a method call.